# Writing SQL query from a given data model

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting, hyperion

I apologize in advance if this question is ambiguous. My SQL skills are very weak and I'm not sure if this question is too general to have a correct answer.

I'm working on a project, converting reports from Hyperion Interactive Reporting (IR) to OBIEE. I'm given a visual of the data model in IR, and I'm trying to write the equivalent SQL query.

The data model looks like this:

```
A --- = --- B --- = --- C
 \-- +=+ --/ \-- +=+ --/
```

The `=` represents an inner join; `+=+` represents a full outer join. Table `B` inner joins and full outer joins to tables `A` and `C`. So I have four joins that I'm trying to piece together:

```
A join B on A.x = B.x
A full outer join B on A.y = B.y
B join C on B.x = C.x
B full outer join C on B.y = C.y
```

Without specifying details of my data, is it possible to write a query that matches the behavior of the data model above? And if so, what is the correct/preferred way to do so?

Comment: simple use inner join in one query and union with full outer join query

Comment: @Ritesh Patel - Would you mind showing how I would write this query? I'm a SQL newbie

Answer (score 0):

Use union/union all as per your requirement

```
A join B on A.x = B.x
B join C on B.x = C.x

union

A full outer join B on A.y = B.y
B full outer join C on B.y = C.y
```

Comment: lastly use group by to make single record